# Publish .NET Core app without EXE and runtimes

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

My question is more academic than a real problem: .NET Core has three different publish modes ([see here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/deploy-with-cli)). I'm interested in *framework-dependent deployment* (FDD) and *framework-dependent executable* (FDE).

As far as I understand, with *framework-dependent deployment* the `publish` folder will contain the project DLL, 3rd party DLLs and the runtimes. The app can only be started via `dotnet run`.

Using *framework-dependent executable*, the `publish` folder will contain the project DLL, the project EXE and 3rd party DLLs, but no runtimes. The app can be both launched via the EXE or `dotnet run`.

Now I'd like to host an ASP.NET Core Web API within IIS. The .NET Core runtime is installed system-wide. So I don't need the EXE and the included runtimes, but both FDE and FDD contain either one of them.

Now my question: is there any publish mode so that the `publish` folder contains a mixture of FDE and FDD, i. e. the DLL, 3rd party DLLs, no EXE and no runtime?

Comment: No, `framework-dependent` *doesn't* contain the runtime. That's what `self-contained` is for. In both cases, you can package everything in a single file.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos when I look into the `publish` folder for FDD, there is a `runtimes` folder with different assemblies. Do you know what they are for?

Answer (score 1):

changing application **.csproj** file like below prevents exe to be written to publish path:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <UseAppHost>false</UseAppHost> 
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Here `<UseAppHost>false</UseAppHost>` makes trick